# How do I make a text visible on the right side of a div onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a FAQ page where I need to put all my questions on the left side of the `div`. When I click on the questions, the respective answer for the question should be visible on the right side of the `div`, on the same page. I have tried many different things, but I'm still not able to do it.

Also, how can I make only the answer to the respective question visible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: place it in td tags of table. you can easily do that

Comment: Please post the code too to see what you have done so far .. should help others identify what should be done to help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926432/click-a-button-to-show-or-hide-a-table

Comment: @user3243063 hope you have checked my answer and the fiddle!

Comment: Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery,
**HTML:**

```
<div> <-- For each question -->
    <div style="float: left;" onclick="showAnswer(this);">Question</div>
    <div style="float: right; display: none;">Answer</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function showAnswer(cntrl)
{
    $(cntrl).next().toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr><td class="question">question1?</td><td class="answer">answer1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="question">question2?</td><td class="answer">answer2</td></tr>
<tr><td class="question">question3?</td><td class="answer">answer3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="question">question4?</td><td class="answer">answer4</td></tr>
<tr></tr>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".answer").hide();
        $(".question").click(function () {
            $(".answer").hide();
            $(this).parent().children(".answer").show();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also store the ID of the answer in the Tag attribute, and then simply when clicked get the tag, and show the corresponding element.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#answers div').hide();
    $('#questions ul li').click(function() {
        var answer = $(this).attr('tag');
        $('#' + answer).show();
    });
});
</script>

<div id="questions" style="float: left;">
    <ul>
        <li tag="answer1">Question 1</li>
        <li tag="answer2">Question 2</li>
        <li tag="answer3">Question 3</li>
        <li tag="answer4">Question 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="answers" style="float: right;">
    <div id="answer1">This is answer 1</div>
    <div id="answer2">This is answer 2</div>
    <div id="answer3">This is answer 3</div>
    <div id="answer4">This is answer 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple JS:

```
function showDiv(id) {  
    for (var i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById('div'+i).style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById('div'+id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

html:

```
<div class="qaContainer" style="width:400px;">
<div class="leftContainer" style="float:left;">
    <a href="javascript:" onClick="showDiv('1');">Question 1</a><br />
    <a href="javascript:" onClick="showDiv('2');">Question 2</a><br />
    <a href="javascript:" onClick="showDiv('3');">Question 3</a><br />
    <a href="javascript:" onClick="showDiv('4');">Question 4</a><br />
</div>
<div class="rightContainer" style="float:right;">
<div id="div1" style="display:block;">Answer1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">Answer2</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none;">Answer3</div>
<div id="div4" style="display:none;">Answer4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you have questions on left side and answers on right side You HTML should look like this

```
<div  id="questions">
    <ul> 
      <li data-qnum="1"></li>
      ...
      <li data-qnum="N"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="answers">
<ul>
<li data-ansnum="1"></li>
...
<li data-ansnum="N"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And CSS should be something like this

```
#questions,#answers{
    float:left;
}
.specialClass{
    color:red;
}
```

Now jquery should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//hide all answers 
$("#answers").find("li").hide();

//and then add click handler on questions

$("#questions").on("click","li",function(e){
// preventdefault prevents any default action so that you may replace li with a or any other tag
e.preventDefault();

// you may also add any special formatting on the question clicked like making it red
 $("#questions").find("li").removeClass('specialClass');
$(this).addClass('specialClass');
var qnum = $(this).data('qnum');
//hide all shown answers     
$("#answers").find("li").hide().each(function(){
// show the correct answer
 var anum =$(this).data('ansnum');
    if(anum==qnum) 
    {$(this).toggle(); }                                  });

                         });
```

Also see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s4HEh/1/

**PS:** Also note that this jquery uses ***proper event delegation syntax*** and ***does not uses Id*** on question so that you may use your id for something more important

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. just a simple way of doing it

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
    #left
    {
        width:50%;
        background-color:Yellow;
        float:left;
    }
    #right
    {
        width:50%;
        background-color:Red;
        float:right;
    }
    .answers
    {
        display:none;
    }

    </style>
    <script src="../JS/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showAnswer(ans) {
            $(".answers").hide();
            $("#" + ans).toggle();

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <div id="left">
   <ul id="questions">
   <li onclick="showAnswer('ans1')">q1</li>
   <li onclick="showAnswer('ans2')">q2</li>
   </ul>
   </div>

   <div id="right">
   right
   <ul id="answers">
   <li id="ans1" class="answers">Answer1</li>
   <li id="ans2" class="answers">Answer2</li>
   </ul>
   </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if this helped.  or if you have any queries.

Comment: What happens when I click first question and then second... this will show both answers, probably not the best thing to do. Hide one and then show the new answer

Comment: @DhruvJoshi: missed the part to hide the other answers .. thank you for letting me know .. have made the changes.